# React PropTypes vs Unit Testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-proptypes

PropTypes of React allow to create custom validators that look like this:

```
 static propTypes = {  
    myPassedArray: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    customProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
        if (!/matchme/.test(props[propName])) {
          return new Error(
            'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
            ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
          );
        }
      },
    }
```

For example, for the value:

```
[{propOne: 'string', propTwo: 2}, {propOne: 1, propTwo: 'value'}];
```

It is possible to validate whether:

- this value is an array
- this value consists of objects
- objects are not instances of arrays
- this value's length is 2
- each object of this value has exactly 2 props
- the value of the first prop of the first object is a string
- the key of the first prop of the first object is propOne
- a.s.o for each value

Should I write this kind of prop validation using PropTypes or it is better to stick to shallow validation with PropTypes and dedicate most of the job to Unit Testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
cont myData = [{propOne: 'string', propTwo: 2}, {propOne: 1, propTwo: 'value'}];
```

This should handle most of your requirements

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  myData: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      propOne: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      propTwo: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    }),
  ).isRequired,
};
```

Comment: But what if I want to be more specific to cover all the possible relevant cases of non-dynamic values (like I showed in the question)? Do you think it is unnecessary? Or should I use unit testing for this instead?

Comment: @Eduard it's hard to say for sure without fully understanding the environment your component lives in, but for me, I keep the validation that PropTypes handles pretty simple

Comment: meaning that you put the more complicated testing to the component testing with utilities like Enzyme, right?